# Why should I use present continuous here

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

In an example sentence of wlingua it said:

Worker: Can I help you? You look like you are having trouble with your basket.
Woman: Actually I am struggling because it seems like the basket is too small for all the shopping.

Worker: No problem. Let me get you a bigger cart.

Woman: Thank you, that's very kind **I am always coming** into this store and buying more than I expected.

Why is the present simple form used here (*coming)* instead of the present simple (come)? I would consider going to the shop a regular act just like I would talk about my favourite shopping mall: "I always come from *The Star* when it's already dark outside.

Comment: "... buying more **than** I expected..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/I am always coming into this store/ uses the progressive to emphasize the action of coming and buying.

Simple present is less  intense in terms of the action of come and buy. Also, the expression: I'm always verb + ing is a quasi-idiom to describe something that is considered negative.

Another example: He's always coming into the house and muddying the floor with his dirty shoes.